# Definitions of adjoints (functional analysis vs category thy)

Tags: category-theory, hilbert-spaces, definition

If I have a linear operator $f$ on a Hilbert space, then I define the adjoint of $f$ to be $f^*$ where,

$(fx,y)=(x,f^*y)$  for all $x,y$.

I am confused because this definitions is very different to the definition of an adjoint used in category theory.

Is there some way to tie these two definitions together?

Thanks

Matthew

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two notions of adjoint are related only by a symbolic similarity, enhanced by the once common but now apparently rare convention of writing $(X,Y)$ for the set of morphisms from $X$ to $Y$ (the category being understood or indicated by a subscript). Then if $L$ is left-adjoint to $R$, we have $(LX,A)\cong(X,RA)$, with obvious notational similarity to the Hilbert space definition of adjoint.

Comment: Banach adjoint (i.e. a $^*$ operation) is functor $\mathcal{B}(-,\mathbb{C})$. As for Hilbert adjoint you need additional cheats with Reisz representation theorem and to make Hilbert adjoint functorial.

Comment: Thank you. Although I am a bit disappointed with the answer, I was hoping there was a cool way of seeing the Hilbert spaces definition  in terms of the category thy one.

Comment: IIRC this is more than a symbolic similarity. See http://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9609018v2

Comment: Andreas' answer is excellent and you can read some more in the "Notes" to the "Adjoints" chapter in CWM.The connection initially was just notational. Even the link to universal properties was not too clear, it seems. Any deeper connection comes much, much later (see @MartinBrandenburg 's link). If you are a beginner in CT, Andreas' answer should suffice. The widespread existence of the adjunction *phenomenon* is a marvelous discovery as it is, the naming is secondary. It could have been called *transposition* or *conjugation* or anything else giving the idea of an (almost) symmetric relation.